# Handling HTTP request by PHP script

Tags: php, apache, httprequest

This question might be more theoretical but I'm missing some knowledge in my head since I've been trying to figure this for two straight days.

If I send HTTP request from mobile APP to my server (which is running apache) to address www.example.com/getData it will be handled by apache and will answer with OK status in following HTTP response.

Now, if I would like to handle this request by php, I guess I would need to configure apache so it redirects HTTP requests to my php script?

But as I was not able to find appropriate answer on google, I started to doubt my knowledge around this. Is this the right way to accomplish what I want?

Answer (score 0):

Try following one in your .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?path=$1 [NC,L]
```

And in index.php, access path as below

```
<?php
      echo $_GET['path'];
?>
```

Comment: Could you explain modifications to .httpaccess?

Comment: It is .htaccess (in your root directory of the domain). It redirects everything afther the / (so http://domain.ext/anything) to index.php?path=anything and so on

Comment: Will then php be able to respond to  request?

Comment: Yes in your index.php you'll be able to use the $_GET['path']

Comment: And php will be able to respond with HTTP message(as apache would in default configuration)?